# How to use a custom download button with default printing options in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, button, highcharts, export

I'd like to use a custom printing button for my Highcharts graph. Now, I succeeded in adding it, however, I don't know how to make it display those default printing options (Export as PNG, SVG, JPG, PDF). And how to make disappear that default printing button.

This is the code:

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            'myButton': {
                _id: 'myButton',
                symbol: 'url(http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/images/button_download.png)',
                onclick: function () {
                    alert('click!')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And [here is](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/ngkt9zs1/2/) a fiddle.

Is there any simple approach for that in the "onClick" event it says: "Display all print options"?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Let me know why you cannot use defult menu and modify only symbol ?  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n0azuvgx/

Comment: @Sebastian: Didn't know that this is possible. Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sebastian showed [in his example](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/n0azuvgx/1/) (I deleted a few unnecessary commands), no need to reinvent the wheel, but just to replace the default image is sufficient:

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                symbol: 'url(http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/images/button_download.png)'
            }
        }
    }
```